# Stop the sound of a video without stoping the video

Tags: ios, video

I have a video with sounds, and I want to play other sounds on the background. So I want to stop the video music to keep playing just the other music. I have to code for all except to stop the music for the video. Is it possible to build?

Comment: How are you playing your video (e.g. MPMoviePlayerController)?  Also, is it possible to take your original video and *remove* the audio track before baking it into (or making it available to) your app?

Comment: No... It is playing in a UIWebView, and audio an image aren't separated. But in my app the best will be to shut up the video, not to remove audio or other "solutions".